# Pub/sub based on events - Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, events, publish-subscribe, amazon-sns

I am trying to build a system where I can send messages to diffferent users based on their subscription to certain events. Basically I have an api which gives me live stream events. Some of the users will be subscribed to those events. My task is to send message to those users whenever such an event occurs. I am trying to design the system in Python.

Currently I have the following questions.

- How yo continously poll for events from a live stream api in Python.
- How to find out which users are subscribed to that particular event. (Redis or Mysql)
- How to send notification to all the users of a particular event. (Pub/sub)

I am thinking of using Amazon SNS. But not quite sure about the overall architecture.

Answer (score 0):

> RabbitMQ is lightweight and easy to deploy on premise and in the
>   cloud. It supports multiple messaging protocols. RabbitMQ can be
>   deployed in distributed and federated configurations to meet
>   high-scale, high-availability requirements.

Just small example:

Producer sends messages to the "hello" queue. The consumer receives messages from that queue. This will create a Queue (hello) with a message on the RabbitMQ cluster.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

RABBITMQ_USERNAME = 'ansible'
RABBITMQ_PASSWORD = 'ansible'

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host='example.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com',
        heartbeat_interval=25,
        credentials=pika.PlainCredentials(RABBITMQ_USERNAME,RABBITMQ_PASSWORD)))

channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='hello',
                      body='Hello World!')
print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
connection.close()
```

Receive a message from a named queue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

RABBITMQ_USERNAME = 'ansible'
RABBITMQ_PASSWORD = 'ansible'

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host='example.elb.amazonaws.com',
        heartbeat_interval=25,
        credentials=pika.PlainCredentials(RABBITMQ_USERNAME,RABBITMQ_PASSWORD)))

channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % body)

channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue='hello',
                      no_ack=True)

print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
channel.start_consuming()
```